# Laravel DataTables JSON column escaping chars

Tags: json, laravel, datatables, laravel-datatables

Trying to use Yajra DataTables as service implementation and here is my problem:

I have JSON column `metas` I building table columns based on fields inside that column, for excample:

`[ 'data' => 'date', 'name' => 'metas->date AS date', 'title' => 'Data' ],`

So inside metas I have:

```
{
    "date": "2018-09-17",
}
```

When I try to return this to DataTable it will leave quotas, or escape it with backslash. So the output looks like:

`"Something"` or `"Something \"mmm?\ whatever!"` but should be jus `Something`.

Tried `->escapeColumns(false)` and `->rawColumns(['date'])` and `->rawColumns(['metas->date'])` and many more...

Response looks like this:

```
{"draw":1,"recordsTotal":77,"recordsFiltered":77,"data":[{"id":43695,"nr":"18-036","date":"\"2018-09-17\""...
```

As you can see I have additional quotes in response near date:
Normally if I return same data from DB with ->toJson() there wouldn't be problem. There is something wrong with DataTables decoding.

Comment: And what is your question? I don't see any, just a description.

Comment: I have unnecessary quotes in response.

Answer (score 0):

By default, the Laravel Datable enforce XSS filter.  You have to disable it in the column or the whole response.

https://yajrabox.com/docs/laravel-datatables/10.0/xss

Comment: Answer could be improved by including the actual change he should make, rather than just a link.